# SQL SERVER PIVOT WITHOUT AGGREGATION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query whose result set looks like the below table.
The Name column has a "C1, C2, C3" set which is well known

```
 Id | Name  | Value
-------------------------------
 1  | C1    | 1C1
 1  | C2    | 1C2
 1  | C3    | 1C3
 2  | C1    | 2C1
 2  | C2    | 2C2
 2  | C3    | 2C3
```

I need to transpose it to the following

```
 Id | C1  | C2  | C3
-------------------------------
 1  | 1C1 | 1C2 | 1C3
 2  | 2C2 | 2C2 | 2C3
```

Tried to achieve it with Pivots but they don't seem to play nice for string values (i.e.) non-aggregates.
Any pointers on how I can go about this ?

Comment: `MAX()` is an aggregate that can work with strings and there's no point in providing special facilities for when the developer happens to know that each aggregate will only receive one row's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is pretty much taken from the sample in the SQL Server documentation; the subquery isn't really needed here, but that's how it's written in the sample.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Id, Name, Value 
    FROM your_table_or_query
    ) AS p
PIVOT
    (MAX(value) 
    FOR Name IN
       (C1,C2,C3)
) AS pvt
ORDER BY ID;
```

Output:

```
Id  C1  C2  C3
1   1C1 1C2 1C3
2   2C1 2C2 2C3
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @source TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, 
                      [Name] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
                      [Value] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @source ( ID, Name, Value )
VALUES  (1,'C1','1C1'),
        (1,'C2','1C2'),
        (1,'C3','1C3'),
        (2,'C1','2C1'),
        (2,'C2','2C2'),
        (2,'C3','2C3');

 SELECT ID, [C1], [C2], [C3]
 FROM @source
 PIVOT (MAX([Value]) FOR [Name] IN ([C1], [C2], [C3])) AS pivotTable;
```